# files upload using java

Tags: java

java code which handles files upload file from location in the system and to save that file to a specific location in the same system

Comment: 1) Did you have a question? 2) SO is not your personal code generation machine. 3) Please find your shift key and apply it at the start of sentences, to help your reader, and also help support the idea that you are not _totally lazy._

Answer (score -4):

```
@Autowired
ServletContext c;

String UPLOAD_FOLDEdR=c.getRealPath("/images");
```

but if you use servlets just use

```
String UPLOAD_FOLDEdR = ServletContext.getRealPath("/images");
```

so the path will be `/webapp/images/` :)